# What are the 2 transistors with markings SP and !SB?

Tags: transistors, identification

I'm trying to identify 2 transistors, Q15 marked 'SP' and Q16 marked '!SB'.

[image]

Comment: Related: *[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/)*, *[Should we keep component identification questions?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6697/)*, and *[Identification questions getting closed formally](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part marked `SB` is a [Fairchild (now Onsemi) BSS123L](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/BSS123L-469259.pdf) N-channel MOSFET.

[image]

The markings were changed on newer parts, but we can see in the following picture of a Onsemi [product bulletin](https://www.mouser.com/PCN/onsemi_Final_PCN_Document_PB22130XA_%2810%29.pdf) that Fairchild/Onsemi used this marking style in the past:

[image]

(Source: [mouser.com](https://www.mouser.com/PCN/onsemi_Final_PCN_Document_PB22130XA_%2810%29.pdf))

---

Since the second part uses a similar marking style, it's likely a [Fairchild/Onsemi BSS84](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view-marking/50818/FAIRCHILD/BSS84.html) P-channel MOSFET.

[image]

Comment: Why is "SB" sufficient to make it unique?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's not unique. There are quite a few parts with the same marking, see [here](https://smd.yooneed.one/code5342.html). That's why I always try to find pictures that confirm that the style of the markings matches as well.